# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre "conducta" y "comportamiento"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Here is the sentence:

> Las religiones quieren aumentar las virtudes de las personas para que tengan una conducta o un comportamiento positivo.

I just want to know, what is the difference between "conducta" and "comportamiento"?

Answer (score 10):

*Conducta* refers mainly to human behaviour, while *comportamiento* is more general. But the difference is mainly of [collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation), I think. There are certain contexts where only one of *conducta* or *comportamiento* is permitted. For example, you can say

> *el comportamiento de las variables meteorológicas*

but you cannot say (or it would be a bit weird to say)

> *la conducta de las variables meteorológicas*

Similarly, you can study *el comportamiento animal* ("animal behaviour") but not *la conducta animal*.

Also, *conducta* tends to imply good behaviour, or (self-)control, while *comportamiento* is neutral (but note that the verb *comportarse* can mean "to behave well", while *conducirse* cannot be used in this way).

It seems that some theories of psychology have a clear distinction between what they formally call *conducta* and *comportamiento*. For example, [on a psychologists' forum](http://www.mundopsicologos.com/consultas/diferencia-entre-conducta-y-comportamiento) I found this:

> A grandes rasgos conducta y comportamiento son términos muy similares.
>   No obstante, existen ciertas diferencias. La conducta es la parte
>   observable del comportamiento ante un estímulo externo. El
>   comportamiento engloba a la conducta e incluye aspectos conscientes,
>   inconscientes, públicos o privados, voluntarios o involuntarios.

Translating: "Broadly speaking, *conducta* and *comportamiento* are very similar terms. However there are some differences. *Conducta* is the observable part of *comportamiento* when faced with an external stimulus. *Comportamiento* includes *conducta* as well as conscious or unconscious, public or private, voluntary or involuntary aspects."

This seems to reinforce the idea that *conducta* means "how a human being chooses to behave" while *comportamiento* means "how something acts or reacts".

Comment: Nice explanation. It looks as though the two terms map quite well to _conduct_ and _behaviour_ in English.